# How to make draggable elements follow the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have several draggable items. When I drag them, helper clones always appear on top of the page. How do I make them follow the mouse while dragging?

I know about `cursorAt: { left: 0, top: 0}` option, but my elements positioning will differ and I don't know at what position the dragging will start. What to do? This is what else I've tried:

```
$('#widget li').draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
            revert: 'invalid',
            cursorAt: { left: helperX, top: helperY },
            start: function(e, ui){
              $('#widget').css({'position': ''});
              helperX = $('#widget li').width()/2;
              helperY = e.pageY - ui.position.top;
            },
            stop: function(){
              $('#widget').css({'position': 'relative'});
            },
            drag: function(){
              $(this).css({'z-index':'1500'});
            }
        });
```

This does not work because `helperX` and `helperY` get defined too late. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/wh6addd6/7/

```js
$('#deviceName li').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid',
  start: function(e, ui) {
    $('#deviceName').css({
      'position': ''
    });
    $(ui.helper).css({
      'top': '400px'
    });
  },
  stop: function() {
    $('#deviceName').css({
      'position': 'relative'
    });
  },
  drag: function() {
    $(this).css({
      'z-index': '1500'
    });
  }
});
$('#interface li').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid',
  start: function(e, ui) {
    $('#interface').css({
      'position': ''
    });
    $(ui.helper).css({
      'top': '400px'
    });
  },
  stop: function() {
    $('#interface').css({
      'position': 'relative'
    });
  },
  drag: function() {
    $(this).css({
      'z-index': '1500'
    });
  }
});


function foo() {
  $('.foo').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
      //containment: $(this).parent(),
      stack: '.foo'
    });
  });
}
var fooCount = $('.foo').length;
$('#mainDiv').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')) {
      var Class = ui.draggable.attr("class");
      var title = ui.draggable.text().trim();
      var item = $('<table class="foo elementTable ' + Class + '" name="' + title + '" id="' + (fooCount + 1) + '"><tr class="tableHeader"><th class="thClass"><button class="settings">set</button>' + title + '<span class="close">x</span></th></tr><tr><td class="add"><span class="addList">Add new link</span></td></tr></table>');
      $(this).append(item);
      fooCount += 1;
      foo();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #b8c0c8;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#leftDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}

#deviceInfo {
  min-height: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 3px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}

#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

#menu li span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu li ul li {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: move;
}

#menu li ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

#menu li ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#settingsDiv {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 3px;
}

.foo {
  min-width: 250px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #515151;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.thClass {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 102%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  margin-top: -2px;
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 19px;
  cursor: move;
}

.header {
  margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
  display: block;
  min-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 102%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  cursor: default;
}

.foo tbody tr td {
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.devInfo {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <div id="deviceInfo">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li>Device Name
          <ul id="deviceName" style="position: relative;">
            <li>
              item 1
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Interface
          <ul id="interface" style="position: relative;">
            <li>
              item 2
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="settingsDiv">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainDiv">

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

```css
#image{
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="http://images.pictureshunt.com/pics/m/image.JPG"/>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the coordinates in the cloned element on the drop (e.g., with `item.css()`. See added code below:

```
var fooCount = $('.foo').length;
$('#mainDiv').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')) {
      var Class = ui.draggable.attr("class");
      var title = ui.draggable.text().trim();
      var item = $('<table class="foo elementTable ' + Class + '" name="' + title + '" id="' + (fooCount + 1) + '"><tr class="tableHeader"><th class="thClass"><button class="settings">set</button>' + title + '<span class="close">x</span></th></tr><tr><td class="add"><span class="addList">Add new link</span></td></tr></table>');
      item.css("left", ui.position.left);  // added
      item.css("top", ui.position.top);  // added
      $(this).append(item);
      fooCount += 1;
      foo();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but probably I could not explain well what I need. What you have mentioned helps to drop the item at the point mouse was released, I'm already using this in my project (Simply did not include here). I need draggable items clone to follow the mouse while dragging. As you see, the clone always appears on top of the page, not near the pointer

Answer (score 0):

Please use 'cursonAt' for stick the draggable element to the mouse like this

```
$('#interface li').draggable({helper: 'clone', cursorAt: { left: 5,top:5 }});
```

Please read jQuery documentation:
[enter link description here](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cursorAt)